# Is there any Cordova plugin for reading data from port on mobile either iPhone or Android

Tags: cordova, mobile, cross-platform

I have RFID reader which connected to mobile phone port.
I want to read data on that port.
And the data that sent from RFID is sent in serial.
Is there any  Cordova plugin to read the data that sent by RFID reader?
Or is there another way to achieve this without using Cordova plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on IoT , i guess that cordova-plugin-serial plugin can shed some light on communication on the External Device with the mobile application . elaborate more on the Problem .
I donot think that JavaScript cannot itself communicate with the WebSocket on the WebUI interface level , But a plugin can.
Hope it Helps